# How do I find a list of Homebrew's installable packages?

Tags: list, macos, installation, package, homebrew

Recently I installed [Brew](https://brew.sh/). How can I retrieve a list of available brew packages to install?

Comment: This is what i was expecting, hope you too >> https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256269

Comment: 2023 UPDATE: check mivk answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77024140/1142814

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people who, like me, land here wanting to search the available packages but are not in front of a Mac with a working Homebrew install:

The Homebrew site now has full lists and a search option on [Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/).

The full lists are on separate pages for:

- Formulas: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/
- Casks: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/

Answer (score 400):

`brew help` will show you the list of commands that are available.

`brew list` will show you the list of installed packages. You can also append formulae, for example `brew list postgres` will tell you of files installed by postgres (providing it is indeed installed).

`brew search <search term>` will list the possible packages that you can install. `brew search post` will return multiple packages that are available to install that have post in their name.

`brew info <package name>` will display some basic information about the package in question.

Answer (score 22):

From the man page:

> ```
> search, -S text|/text/
> Perform a substring search of formula names for text. If text is surrounded with slashes,
> then it is interpreted as a regular expression. If no search term is given,
> all available formula are displayed.
> ```

For your purposes, `brew search` will suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Since Homebrew 2.6.0 released in 2020.12.01, `brew list` behaves a little differently. This is one of the reason I post the following answer.

#### Installed Packages

Homebrew describes packages as formulae. There's another kind of package know as cask, which is used for GUI apps installed by `brew install --cask`.

Formerly, `brew list` will only list installed formulae. After 2.6.0, `brew list` will list both of packages and casks. You may wanna check them separately

- `brew list --formula`
- `brew list --cask`

#### Available Packages

List

- `brew formulae`, list all available formulae
- `brew casks`, list all casks (These two commands are fast cause it's implemented in Bash not Ruby)

Search

```bash
# search local installed
brew search --formula keyword
brew search --cask keyword

# search online available
brew search --formulae keyword
brew search --casks keyword
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use Homebrew Formulae page to see the list of installable packages.
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/

To install any package => command to use is :

**brew install node**

Answer (score 1):

To list all homebrew packages (whether installed or not):

```
brew search '/[a-zA-Z]/'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since some of the other answers have been written quite a few changes have been made to the `brew` command.  It took me a while to figure out, but the following command will list all available packages:

```
brew search --eval-all --desc ""
```